# Change Qt Stylesheet for all buttons of a Widget on button press

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I want to change all the button instances stylesheets of a widget, much like this question I found ([Change Qt Stylesheet for all Instances of a Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194737/change-qt-stylesheet-for-all-instances-of-a-widget)), however, I want to have a theme button so there is multiple stylesheets that I want to use in this manor.

In the example it changes all the button stylesheets on start up, I want to be able to do that within a function.

Any advice as to achieve this?

Comment: The concept is the same, `app.setStyleSheet(...)`, if you want it more consistent and correct, use `QApplication.instance()` instead of `app`.

Comment: so if i went and did something like:

app = QApplication.instance();
app.setStyleSheet(...);

I'd work? (Cant test it now)

Comment: There's no point in creating a local variable if you're not using it again, just do as said, use `QApplication.instance()` *instead* of app: `QApplication.instance().setStyleSheet(...)`.

Comment: Ill be using it multiple times in certain cases. But thanks.